# parsing a chinese page with PHP

Tags: php, curl, utf-8

I would like to extract some informations from a chinese page.

The source page is encoded with **content="text/html; charset=gb2312"**

Is it possible to make an "universal" utf8 "translator" with encoding (utf8, iso, gb...) ?

I try this but it doesn't work with chinese :

```
[...]

$return = curl_exec($curl);

if ( !mb_check_encoding( $return, 'UTF-8' ) ) {
    $return = utf8_encode($return);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`utf8_encode` only converts from ISO-8859-1 so is useless for your purpose. `iconv` is more suitable for converting from one encoding to another as long as you know the source encoding.

Use it like so:

```
echo iconv('GB2312', 'UTF-8', $return);
```

Comment: And if I don't know that is encoded in GB2312 ? Is it possible to have a string correctly encoded in UTF8 ?

Comment: `mb_detect_encoding` can be used to try to detect the source encoding. It can never be 100% accurate but might be good enough, especially when using GB2312